# jQuery Colorbox works on other pages but not my index.html

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm pretty sure I thoroughly searched for a similar occurrence to this...hope I didn't overlook it and I apologize if I did.

I'm installing this on my live site:
[www.sigmarating.com](http://www.sigmarating.com)

Now as you can see at [www.sigmarating.com/index2.html](http://www.sigmarating.com/index2.html), the example1 colorbox is working flawlessly. Now when I go to implement the SAME header scripts and stylesheet links in the index.html ... nothing happens when you click the links.

index.html:

```
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Sigma Rating TM</title>
     <meta name="description" content="">
     <meta name="author" content="">
     <!-- +++ Mobile Specific Metas +++ -->
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
     <!-- +++ Load all the CSS Files with styles.css +++ -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
     <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
     <![endif]-->
     <!-- +++ Load Favicon Favicons +++  -->
     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
     <!--COlorbox header!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" rel='javacsript' type='text/js'></script>
    <script src="http://www.sigmarating.com/jquery.colorbox-min.js" rel='javascript' type='text/js'></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
            $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
            $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
            $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
            $(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
            $(".ajax").colorbox();
            $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
            $(".vimeo").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:500, innerHeight:409});
            $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
            $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
            $(".callbacks").colorbox({
                onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
                onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
                onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
                onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
                onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
            });

            $('.non-retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none'})
            $('.retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none', retinaImage:true, retinaUrl:true});

            //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
            $("#click").click(function(){ 
                $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

HTML External Page ColorBox im trying to call:

```
<p><a class='iframe' href="http://www.sigmarating.com/SIRcalculator/SIR.html">SIR Calculator</a></p>
```

Im using the Barbershop Responsive Layout -- ThemeForest if anyone is at all familiar with it. I'm not using wordpress or drupal or any other CMS just a plain cut and dry responsive theme.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

-Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this was a simple one that went completely over my head. The theme i'm using loaded the JavaScripts at the end of the page to speed up load times. I guess I just never bothered to look down there because I had already loaded another script in the header and that script worked fine. However, the ColorBox jQuery plugin needed to be loaded with the other scripts.

Thanks to the theme's Support team for helping me clarify my stupidity.

```
                <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
                <script src="assets/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
                <script src="assets/js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
                <script src="assets/js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
                <script src="assets/js/filter-gallery.js"></script>
                <script src="assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
                <script src="assets/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
                <!-- Initiate JQuery -->
                <script src="assets/js/js.js"></script>
                <script src="assets/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
```

That's how the scripts ended up looking in the end, where the call functions were placed inside of "assets/js/js.js" .